# Dotnet core 1.1 on linux: Any particular way thats better than others when seeding data with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, seeding

I was thinking about just doing a migration, and seeding the data in that migration. I am not sure if i want seeding to be part of my migrations, maybe there comes a time when i want a clean slate.

Last time i did asp.net about a year ago on windows i had the following implementation:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using Mentor.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
/**
 * Author: matti
 */
namespace Mentor.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Mentor.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            /*if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
               System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();*/
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            ContextKey = "Mentor.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(Mentor.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher();
                User user1 = new User()
                {
                    UserName = "mattinielsen5@hotmail.com",
                    PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword("Denherpderp21!"),
                    FirstName = "Matti andreas",
                    LastName = "Nielsen",
                    Age = 24,
                    ProfileText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, minimum delicatissimi ad eos, " +
                                  "ne veniam eirmod voluptatibus vel, ne eam facilisi inciderint. " +
                                  "Ex eleifend recteque delicatissimi eos, ut erat posse etiam pri." +
                                  " Ei qui commune vivendum legendos, augue accusata in vim, mei at" +
                                  " bonorum pericula definitionem. Has ornatus aliquando vulputate " +
                                  "at, nonumes docendi in mel. Ne duo recusabo percipitur, et nam " +
                                  "vitae nostrud cotidieque, cibo liber mel te.",
                    IsMentor = true,
                    IsMentee = false,
                    UndefinedInterests = new List<Interest>
                    {

                    },
                    MentorInterests = new List<Interest>
                    {

                    },
                    ... blabla alot of entities ...
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                //some error handling
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i want something like a seed method, so i was thinking about making my own seed method being called in startup.cs depending on some environment variable like development.  My question is, how do you guys do it - or how would you do it??

EDIT:

I am considering doing it like this, when creating the model:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
  {
    //One-to-one
     modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasOne(a => a.Player).WithOne(p =>   p.Account).HasForeignKey<Player>(p => p.AccountForeignKey);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasOne(g => g.Role).WithOne(r => r.Group).HasForeignKey<Role>(r => r.GroupForeignKey);
    modelBuilder.Entity<GameEvent>().HasOne(e => e.Event);
    modelBuilder.Entity<GameEvent>().HasOne(e => e.Game);
    modelBuilder.Entity<TeamEvent>().HasOne(e => e.Event);
    modelBuilder.Entity<TeamEvent>().HasOne(e => e.Team);
    modelBuilder.Entity<GroupEvent>().HasOne(e => e.Event);
    modelBuilder.Entity<GroupEvent>().HasOne(e => e.Group);

    //one-to-many
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasMany(p => p.Integrations).WithOne(i => i.Player);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasMany(p => p.Followers);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasMany(p => p.Activities).WithOne(a => a.Player);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>().HasMany(g => g.GameEvents).WithOne(ge => ge.Game);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>().HasMany(g => g.Teams).WithOne(t => t.Game);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasMany(t => t.TeamEvents).WithOne(te => te.Team);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasMany(g => g.GroupEvents);

    //many to many
    modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerGames>().HasKey(pg => new {pg.PlayerId, pg.GameId});
    modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerTeams>().HasKey(pt => new {pt.PlayerId, pt.TeamId});
    modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerGroups>().HasKey(pg => new {pg.PlayerId, pg.GroupId});

    //discriminator values
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
        .HasDiscriminator<string>("Type")
        .HasValue<GameEvent>("GameEvent")
        .HasValue<GroupEvent>("GroupEvent")
        .HasValue<TeamEvent>("TeamEvent");

    CALLING SEED DATA DOWN HERE, that should be fine???
}
```

Comment: are you using `EF core` or `EF 6.X` ?

Comment: I am using ef core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended approach is to run the seeding code within a service scope in `Startup.Configure()`.

It's like this :

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
       var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyContext>();       
       context.Database.Migrate();
       context.EnsureSeedData();
 }
```

You can see more details about this on below link.

[**Implementing Seeding EF Core 1.0**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/29/implementing-seeding-custom-conventions-and-interceptors-in-ef-core-1-0/)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Sampath's answer, but had too much to add for a quick edit to his answer. A few observations:

1. Very similar (duplicate?) questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034137/asp-net-core-rc2-seed-database)
2. This question+answer and the others seems specific to `EF Core`. That's my situation.
3. Specifically OP shows us their previous implementation; the `DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>.Seed()` method (from `EF 6`); @Sampath's link makes [the same observation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829453(v=vs.113).aspx) -- so it must be common for readers to migrate from `EF 5/6` to `EF Core`; that's also my situation.
4. @Sampath's answer focuses on `using` of a new serviceScope returned from `GetService()`, as advised in [@Sampath's link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/29/implementing-seeding-custom-conventions-and-interceptors-in-ef-core-1-0/), which is a pattern created in [response to this git issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3070), **where the user had already disposed of their DbContext**. This pattern is also seen in other answers, all of which ([except for this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34537483/1175496)) call `GetService()` or `GetRequiredService()` and I don't think that's necessary.

**My Answer:**

You can get your DbContext directly from dependency injection into `Startup.Configure(...)`

Neither @Sampath nor either of the two links explain what happens in `context.EnsureSeedData()` (maybe that's obvious to some readers, but not for me). So I explain below

I believe the [intro to `EF (Core) MVC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) offers a solution; it creates:

1. a static class `DbInitializer`
2. a class ... with one static function called `Initialize` which "ensures the seed data is there". And so, its details (see below) were helpful substitute for the implementation of `EnsureSeedData()` method; maybe other users will find it helpful
3. a static function ... which is passed a `DbContext` (which is presumably **not disposed**; if you've disposed of it you should probably follow @Sampath's answer and/or the others, [which will `GetService()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536021/seed-initial-data-in-entity-framework-7-rc-1-and-asp-net-mvc-6/38967937#38967937)), and possibly introduce a new `using` block
4. a static function... which is called in (at the end?) of `Startup.Configure()` -- same as @Sampath's

The static `Initialize` aka "ensure seed" function  does these key things:

1. Ensures database is created: `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`; this achieves "ensure"
2. Checks for any rows in one table (you might want to check in *each* table, you might want to check for *specific* rows) and if there are rows (assumes this function was already executed, and so `return`; this means it is "idempotent" and can be safely executed multiple times on each startup , but only seed once
3. If there were *not* any rows; it inserts some rows; this achieves the "seed"; guarantees there are rows (by adding object literals and calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

As seen here:

```
public static class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(SchoolContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Look for any students.
        if (context.Students.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }

        var students = new Student[]
        {
            new Student{FirstMidName="Carson",LastName="Alexander",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01")}, ...
        };
        foreach (Student s in students)
        {
            context.Students.Add(s);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
        ...
```

Then call the function with a dependency-injected `DbContext` like this:

> First, add the context to the method signature so that ASP.NET dependency injection can provide it to your DbInitializer class.2

```
public void Configure(..., ..., SchoolContext context)
{
```

> Then call your DbInitializer.Initialize method at the end of the
>   Configure method.

```
    ...
    DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
}
```